# How to provide custom UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning and use default UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning for a navigation controller

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiviewanimationtransition

How to provide custom `UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning` and use default `UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning` for a navigation controller

```
#pragma mark UINavigationControllerDelegate

- (id <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
                                   animationControllerForOperation:(UINavigationControllerOperation)operation
                                                fromViewController:(UIViewController *)fromVC
                                                  toViewController:(UIViewController *)toVC {
  // Return custom transitioner
}

-(id<UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning>)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController interactionControllerForAnimationController:(id<UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning>)animationController {
  return nil; // Use the deafult UIViewControllerInteractiveTransitioning here
}
```

Answer (score -1):

There could be hacky ways, but not a clean way.

[image]